# Getting page level test results in Sitecore 7.2

Tags: sitecore, ab-testing, sitecore7.2, sitecore-dms

I'm doing a page level test (A/B test) and Sitecore 7.2 doesn't have an out of the box tool to get the results.

Does anyone know a tool for this or a good way to query the analytics database to fetch a result using the test item's GUID?

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be little support for Page Level testing prior to Sitecore 8 - though it can be done.

This document (applicable to 6.6) has instructions on how to setup a Page level test and it is not as straight forward as a component level test.

http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/66/marketing_operations_cookbook_sc66-a4.pdf

As for stats as to which page is more effective, there are no default reports you can run as far as I'm aware, but you should be able to see which variant of the page had the most engagement value points to determine which is the most successful. You could try using the Engagement Analytics Report to see this data.

You could try installing this module to see if there are any useful reports which would help with testing.

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/SBOS_Accelerators.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Page Editor, take a look at the following [article](http://www.roundedcube.com/Blog/2014/sitecore-dms-quick-win-5-multivariate-testing):

> Once you click "Stop Test", you'll be presented the results, each
>   content variant's Engagement Value produced. You'll simply click the
>   option you deem the "winner" and that content will be displayed to
>   users. Test complete. Real objective data. Optimized content with
>   provable results.